# Re-did my experiment, how to properly mention it?

Tags: thesis, masters, writing

After doing and evaluating my experiment/model, I decided to redo it (changed some small things based on the results of that experiment), because I believe that this new way would give me even more insight into what I am studying.

How do I properly report this in a thesis? Specifically, where do I mention the description of the second experiment that was done?

The structure of my master thesis is this:

...
4. Experimental procedure
5. Results
6. Discussion
7. Conclusion

Currently I have the original experiment/method in the 'Experiment' section, but I am struggling to find a good place to mention the second/improved experiment/method.

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This is something to discuss with your advisor, but I can make a suggestion.

Some research that is based on constructed models turns out to be questionable if the model lacks stability and resiliency (robustness). There is a branch of science/math called [*catastrophe theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory) in which small changes to a system can produce dramatic, non-continuous, results. One way to guarantee that this is not the case is to tweak the model in small ways and determine if the outputs are also similarly small. If not, the model is too sensitive and may not give usable results.

So, what you have done, can be considered a validity check on your model and can be presented as such in a separate section. You have gained some evidence that the model is stable in some dimension. This could come after section 4 and before section 7, depending on how you want to write it up.

But your advisor's advice would be valuable.

Comment: Thanks. I have already emailed my advisor, but havent recieved a reply yet, so I thought I would ask here in the meantime. Im still struggling to figure out the best place/section to mention the repeated experiment. Im leaning towards just putting it in the results section, after mentioning the results of the first experiment, and then just mentioning what changes I made, followed by the results of the second experiment.